# Conditionally grouped histograms from my dataset

Tags: r, statistics, grouping, histogram

My current dataset `data.df` comes from about 420 students who took an 8-question survey under one of 3 instructors. `escore` is my outcome variable of interest.

```
    'data.frame':   426 obs. of  10 variables:
     $ ques01: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 ...
     $ ques02: int  0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ ques03: int  0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 ...
     $ ques04: int  1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ ques05: int  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
     $ ques06: int  1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ ques07: int  0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 ...
     $ ques08: int  0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 ...
     $ inst  : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ escore: int  3 1 5 5 3 3 4 4 2 5 ...
```

I'm wondering how I can generate `escore` histograms that are conditionally separated based upon the value of `inst` for a given observation. In my head, the pseudo-code might look like this:

```
    par(mfrow=c(1,3)) 
    hist(escore, data.df$inst = 1)
    hist(escore, data.df$inst = 2)
    hist(escore, data.df$inst = 3)
```

but of course that won't work :-(

Ideally, my histograms would look like this:

[3 separate histograms of ~140 observations each, grouped according to their "inst" value http://terpconnect.umd.edu/~briandk/escoreHistogramsbyInstructor-1.png](http://terpconnect.umd.edu/~briandk/escoreHistogramsbyInstructor-1.png)

As usual, I sense there's got to be an easy way to do this. In whatever "conditional/grouping" sense I can extract these graphs from my data, I assume it's **got** to be generalizable for all sorts of plots you'd want to make based on certain conditions.

Also, I'm really sorry if this question has been answered before. My primary difficulty is in figuring out how to ask it in a way that makes sense.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: FYI, these are bar charts, not histograms, because the x axis is discrete.

Comment: @Hadley - Of course you're right, but that's because I made a poor artistic choice. What I sought, though, were histograms.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the lattice package:

```
library(lattice)
histogram( ~ escore | inst, data=X)
```

if `X` is your data.frame object.

Comment: You can't beat lattice for it's beauty in conditioning.

Comment: @Dirk - that definitely worked. What does specifying the "pipe" (|) do in this particular command?

@Vince - agreed. This did exactly what I wanted.

Comment: In the lattice framework,  you specify the conditioning variable after the "pipe" symbol.  There are lots and lots of options -- see the help page, the lattice book and online tutorials you may find via Google.

Answer (score 12):

You can also do this in ggplot2:

```
data.df <- data.frame(inst = factor(sample(3, 426, replace=TRUE)), 
                      escore = sample(5, 426, replace=TRUE))
qplot(escore, fill=inst, data=data.df) + facet_wrap(~inst, ncol=3)
```

[alt text http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~jcone/hists.png](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~jcone/hists.png)